# Integrating an issue, feature request and bug tracking system into an existing ASP.NET Web App

Tags: asp.net

I have an existing asp.net application that is currently in production for more than 3 years now. That application was developped based on internal and user requirements. That application is also using Google Analytics to detect different usage metrics to understand more what users are doing and which part of the system is most requested. But... we understand now that we are not so well connected to client's need's and more importantly, we don't receive a lot of feedback from them and when we receive feedback, that feedback is sent to many different people so most of the time they are lost or missing some valuable informations. Here is my question: is there some free (or paid) products that can be incorporated into an existing asp.net application that can provide the following functionnalities:

For my users:

- Send feedbacks
- Log bugs
- Submit feature request
- Ask questions
- Be able to follow an issue, bug or feature and subscribe to it
- Be able to rate answers
- Be able to include attachments
- Be able to vote for issues to prioritize them
- Etc.

For me:

- Respond to all of these issues and be able, in some way, to see and analyze all of this data to properly populate our product backlog with what user needs

My real need will be to have something like Telerik has implemented. Is there something that can be incorporated into an existing application?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [User Voice](http://uservoice.com/)? It's a great system to collect user feedback. Not sure if you'd get the integration you're looking for. For the rest of your requirements it seems it would work really well.

Comment: That seems to cover my needs. I didn't see anything about sending attachments but maybe it is already included but even if not, all the features of User Voice will make my life easier. Thanks Claudio, I'll make a try of it.

Comment: Attachments can be added, this is included in the premium plan : http://uservoice.com/plans